# SSIS DataFlow - Lookup Transformation Editor - Connections (parameters): "User a table or a view"

Tags: ssis

We have SQL Server 2016 backend...
Why does the list of table or view in double-quotes ("schemaname"."table/viewname") in one environment and brackets ([schema-name].[table/view-name]) in another environment?  Is it because of the OLE DB connection driver or is there a configuration that can be set.  Currently in our DEV (VS 2019) it recognizes brackets but moving the package to PROD (VS 2017), we get configuration error and has to re-select the table or view from the dropdown list again which is double-quoted around the object name.

Comment: What do you mean by `DEV (VS 2019)` and `PROD (VS 2017)`?  Is visual studio installed on these servers and that's how you are configuring them?  What version of SQL is installed on dev and prod and is there any differences in the connection string for the connection manager that you reference in the lookup component?

Comment: We do have different versions of Visual Studio installed on there servers so that we can run interactively directly there.  We are running SQL Server 2016 and the Connection Manager has the same ConnectionString of Data Source=DB_Server;Initial Catalog=DataStaging;Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultiSubnetFailover=True;Application Name=SSIS-DW_Custom-{343412C2-86C6-4A99-9147-9F25A68B1FB9}DS_cm;

Comment: I have no idea why there would be a difference in the table names other than if you switched providers and were using ADO vs OLEDB -- which is not the case.  It would help to have the same of everything (same version of VS), but I'd rather not encourage having development tools on the server at all.  I would be curious if the package would run if you deployed it to the catalog and ran it from a SQL Agent job.

Comment: The package does run if I was to just copied the package from DEV to PROD and the SQL Agent Job execute it.  Seems like this is if we opened in VS that it would complained about it and needed to re-select the table.

Comment: ok, that's good.  So I would say as next steps, install the same version of VS and the SSIS extension on prod and see if that resolves the issue